# When proving if a subset is a subspace, can I prove closure under addition and multiplication in a single proof?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I'm learning about proving whether a subset of a vector space is a subspace.

It is my understanding that to be a subspace this subset must:

- Have the $0$ vector.
- Be closed under addition (add two elements and you get another element in the subset).
- Be closed under multiplication by a scalar (one element by any scalar yields another element in the subset).

---

> Have a subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$:
>
> $$S = \{(t-2s,-s,t) \ / \ t,s \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
>
> Prove that it is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

---

**Does it have the $0$ vector?**

Well yeah, take $t = s = 0$ and you get $(0,0,0).$

**Is it closed under addition?**

We want to show that

$$x + y \in S$$

For some $x,y \in S$.

So we got

$$x = (t_1-2s_1,-s_1,t_1)\\
y = (t_2-2s_2,-s_2,t_2)$$

Then

$$x + y = (t_1-2s_1,-s_1,t_1) + (t_2-2s_2,-s_2,t_2)\\
(t_1+t_2-2s_1-2s_2 , -s_1-s_2, t_1+t_2)\\$$

Now let

$$a = t_1+t_2\\
b = s_1+s_2\\$$

So the above expression would be

$$(a-2b, -b, a)$$

Since $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we prove that it is closed under addition.

**Is it closed under multiplication?**

We want to show that

$$x\cdot r \in S$$

For some $x\in S, r \in \mathbb{R}$.

Have

$$x = (t-2s, -s, t)$$

Then

$$x \cdot r = (r\cdot(t-2s) , r\cdot -s, r\cdot t)\\
(tr-2sr , -sr , tr)$$

Let

$$a = tr\\
b = sr$$

We would have

$$(a-2b, -b, a)$$

Since $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, this is also closed under multiplication.

---

I have a doubt:

Somebody also solved this, but instead of proving the addition and the multiplication closures separately, they did it in a single proof rather than two. They proved something like

> Have $x,y \in S$ and some $r \in \mathbb{R}$, we want to prove that
>   $$x + r\cdot y \in S$$

Then they proceeded to do something similar as any of the two proofs I did above (evaluate and then assign constants $a$ and $b$). Does that mean that, for future proofs, does it suffice to prove $x + r\cdot y \in S$ to prove that it is a subspace? Is there no need to do it separately?

Comment: Yes. If $r=1$ then you are proving that it is closed under addition and if $x=0$ you are proving that it is closed under product by scalars. So it is a way to unify both questions.

Comment: @ManuelFdzLpz: That's an answer.

Comment: Sorry. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: In fact if you can prove that $ax+by\in S$ for all $a,b\in\mathbb R$ and $x,y\in S$ then you can skip checking for the zero vector as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If r=1 then you are proving that it is closed under addition and if x=0 you are proving that it is closed under product by scalars. So it is a way to unify both questions.

Comment: Reckon this would apply to any problem of this kind, or only certain ones?

Comment: Any subspace verification proof, yes.

Comment: This would apply to any problem consisting of showing that a subset of a vectorial space is a vectorial subspace. Even it shows that $0\in S,$ since $r$ is arbitraty. In particular, $x=0$ and $r=0$ shows that the vector $0$ belongs to $S.$